# Unable to make CMT transactions work

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I am developing a small application for my self learning in struts2, ejb and JPA (Hibernate as a provide) with application server as Wildfly 10. I am trying to configure JTA to manage the transactions with the container. Below is my code

Business Service (EJB)

```
 @Stateless
    @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
    public class BusinessService implements BusinessRemote {

        @EJB
        Dao bDao;

        @Override
        @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
        public void updateAll(){
            try {
                dao.saveAll(xyz);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printstacktrace();
            }
            try {
                dao.updateAll();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printstacktrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

DaoImpl (EJB)

```
    @Stateless
    @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
    public class DaoImpl implements Dao {

        @PersistenceContext(unitName="db")
        private EntityManager entityManager;

        public void saveAll(xyz) {
                entityManager.persist(xyz);
            }

        public void updateAll() {
                Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("getQuery.ById");
                query1.executeUpdate();

        }
    }
```

persistence.xml

```
    <persistence-unit name="db" transaction-type="JTA">
            <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
            <jta-data-source>java:/DB</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform" />
                <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="jta"/>
                <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl" />
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
```

But I get below stack trace when `updateAll` method is executed.

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

It seems that when the update query is fired there is no active transaction present. When I try to execute `saveAll` method only then nothing gets saved in the database although I don't receive any exception. If I try to flush the changes then it gives below exception.

```
 javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

So It means that in the above scenario container is not initiating any transaction at all. It seems that there is something missing in my configurations which I am not able to find.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing some properties in `persistence.xml`

Correct one is

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="jta"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
```